# Power Series Expansion for $\log(\frac{1}{1-x})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I prove that the power series expansion

$$
  \log{\big(\frac{1}{1 - x}\big)} = \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m}}{m}
$$

is valid for every real $0 \leq x < 1$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that $\frac{d}{dx}(-\log(1-x))=\frac{1}{1-x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Start with

$$S=1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots$$

$$xS=x+x^2+x^3+\dots$$

Subtract the two as follows:

$$\begin{align}S&=1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots\\xS&=\quad\ \ \ x+x^2+x^3+\dots\\\hline(1-x)S&=1\end{align}$$

$$S=\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots$$

Can you figure out what the following is?

$$\int_0^t\frac1{1-x}dx=\int_0^t1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots dx$$